# Moodle get all quizzes/activities in a course

Tags: moodle

How to get all activities/quizzes from course object ?
I need to get all active quizzes in a course.

Version Moodle 2.8.5
Regards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using method get_array_of_activities(courseId) from course/lib.php, i got the activities objects as an array.

Comment: Very helpful to get all activities details.